# Grails with CSV (No DB)

Tags: csv, grails, groovy

I have been building a grails application for quite a while with dummy data using MySQL server, this was eventually supposed to be connected to Greenplum DB (postgresql cluster). 
But this is not feasible anymore due to firewall issues.

We were contemplating connecting grails to a CSV file on a shared drive( which is constantly updated by greenplum DB, data is appended hourly only)
These CSV files are fairly large(3mb, 30mb and 60mb) The last file has 550,000+ rows.
Quick questions:

1. **Is this even feasible?** Can CSV be treated as a database and can grails directly access this CSV file and run queries on it, similar to that of a DB?
2. Assuming this is feasible, **how much rework** will be required in the grails codes in Datasource, controller and index ( Currently, we are connected to Mysql and we filter data in controller and index using sql queries and ajax calls using remotefunction)
3. Will the constant reading( csv -> grails ) and writing (greenplum -> csv) render the csv file corrupt or bring up any more problems?

I know this is not a very robust method, but I really need to understand the feasibility of this idea. Can grails function wihtout any DB and merely a CSV file on a shared drive accesssible to multiple users?

Comment: If you have access to the csv then why not populate that csv data into a RDMS or NOSQL like Mongo using a script. You could run a cron which keeps reading the CSV file and populates any DB of your choice. You could then use grails with the populated DB.

Comment: If we follow this method, will the RDMBS/MongoDB be a prerequisite for  using the grails application which will be deployed later for multiple users?

Comment: I think yes. You will have to have your db setup wherever you are going to deploy it. Or, you could set up DB at one machine and configure all the deployments datssource to use db setting of that machine.

Comment: +1 for using H2 and also use spring batch, integration or apache camel to handle the feeding of the data.

Comment: Lalit, for everyone to use a particular machine's datasource, won't they need to be connected to the same network(intranet) all the time for it to be used?

cfrick, is it possible to use H2 to store my CSV files, which need to be updated in an hourly manner? And can this then be packaged and WAR file sent across to multiple users, will the CSV files keep updating within the H2 DB?

Comment: H2 http://h2database.com/html/main.html can run embedded in your war deployment; if you always only use the csv for all users you can use the memory-only config (e.g. grails' `test` environment uses this; see the `DataSource.groovy`).  so you could bootstrap from the CSV and then update scheduled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, No. This won't be a good solution.

1. No.
2. It would be nearly impossible, if at all possible to rework this.
3. Concurrent access to a file like that in any environment is a recipe for disaster.

Grails is not suitable for a solution like this.

**update:**
Have you considered using the built in H2 database which can be packaged with the Grails application itself? This way you can distribute the database engine along with your Grails application within the WAR. You could even have it populate it's database from the CSV you mention the first time it runs, or periodically. Depending on your requirements.

Comment: Are you saying that having a DB is absolutely necessary? Without a DB, doing all of it in a CSV is a completely impossible?

Comment: What I am saying is that you can't replace a database which is designed for data storage and manipulation with multiple users with a CSV which is a plain text file. You can use Grails without a database. I have a few projects which do so. But you can't and shouldn't ever replace a DB with a CSV like this.

Comment: So is it possible to store all the CSV files in the H2 DB of grails?
If it was a shared drive, we had the option of updating these files by a pyhton script, how can this be incorporated in the H2 DB? Is scheduling possible in H2 DB, assuming we can load these files there?

Comment: It's possible to have your Grails application use Quartz to schedule something within the application to parse the CSV file and import it into the H2 DB. Obviously you would have to write the transformation/import/sync but it could be done.

Comment: Joshua, can you share the projects where CSV files were loaded and used in grails, the documentation is not clear and wanted to test a couple of things there. I am also looking into H2 DB and checking the feasibility of loading CSV files there.

Comment: @user3825692 search the web for "spring batch csv example".  also there is a grails plugin for _spring batch_

Comment: @user3825692 You can have Grails application without any DB support. For example, I have an web-application which talking with server through the REST. But web-app has all the domains. So of course you can write your own provider which will operate with that domains. Even also you may write your own hibernate driver to CSV.