# Import CSV in H2 DB of grails

Tags: mongodb, csv, grails, deployment, h2

This is a continuation to the question : [Grails with CSV (No DB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692738/grails-with-csv-no-db/24692848#24692848)

I have three CSV files as my backend(in shared drive), which are constantly being updated by the greenplum DB (rows being appended) and I want to import these files in the H2DB (default) of grails and then use these files.
The CSV files are 3mb, 30mb and 60 mb in size and the last one has 550,000 rows.
These CSV files are updated hourly with new data(appending rows)

The scheduling can be done by Quartz here.
Quick questions :

1. **Is this feasible?** Can H2 DB store this much data? While deploying the app, will the WAR file then store all this data? Will the users not have to install any other DB then when this application is deployed ?
2. Secondly, is it possible to store these files in MongoDB, which can be hosted in one machine and the datasource can be configured to take the data from this machine only?
3. Basically, when the application is deployed, I don't want users to install any thing 
   (except the servlet container like Apache, which I'm guessing is compulsory, or is it not?
   They should just use the WAR file and run the application. Am I correct/wrong here?

Comment: I would like you to take a look at the meta-question "[Are multi-point questions bad style?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208859/are-multi-point-questions-bad-style)"

Comment: Understood philipp, will keep these in mind for future questions, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is this feasible? Yes. H2 can stored the data to disk, there is an in-memory mode (see the docs).
2. Is it possible to store these files in MongoDB? Yes... but why would you want to do that?

Comment: yeah I'm reading the docs currently and found the csv import statements written clearly. But I don't understand where do I put these codes in the grails application. In a controller's actions etc?
But these are in groovy and there will be quite a few changes in that, wont there?

Comment: this link pretty much sums up what I want to do and also how to do! But I'm still facing issues with what to put on the controller.Also is it possible to use remotefunction, ajax calls and paramtrized query in the method explained in the link? 
http://redpointtech.blogspot.in/2010/10/using-h2-database-csvread-with-sequence.html

Comment: @user3825692 I'm sorry but I don't know Groovy and Grails. I think it's better to ask those questions a separate, new question.

Comment: Ok I have asked it as a separate question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758494/using-h2-default-db-in-grails

But, can you tell me where H2 DB lies in case of Grails? What does it mean by being the default DB of grails?

Comment: I don't know where H2 lies in case of Grails, because it depends on the configuration.