# Using H2 default DB in Grails

Tags: csv, grails, h2

This is a follow up question of : [Import CSV in H2 DB of grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699676/import-csv-in-h2-db-of-grails/24703014?noredirect=1#comment38412873_24703014)

I am trying to use the default H2 DB of grails, which can link and load the three CSV files in  the DB and query them whenever possible.
My entire codes for Grails where written with MySQL as a dummy DB, I have used and implemented AJAX calls also in controller/index using remotefunction.

Can all of these be used in the same format when I change my datasource to H2 DB ?

I am not able to find any documentation on H2 for grails/groovy support.

However, this link explains my problem very correctly and also offers a solution :
http://redpointtech.blogspot.in/2010/10/using-h2-database-csvread-with-sequence.html

I am not able to understand the link and implement it completely as I'm a beginner in grails, H2 etc

Can someone tell me where I can get any documentation regarding using H2 Db of Grails, storing files (CSV) in it, querying them and using AJAX calls within it.

All feedbacks are highly appreciated

Update :

The default DB of grails is H2, what does this mean exactly?

Can this defualt DB store CSV files while the app is being deployed etc?